# How can we expose a runtime constant?

Tags: runtime, query, constants

I have a situation where I have a constant defined in my `runtime` (but not in any `pallet`) which I want to expose with the runtime itself in some way.

Specifically, there is a constant used as a multiplier in our runtime's `WeightToFee` implementation. This multiplier used to be part of `transaction-payment`'s constants until https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11415 converted `WeightToFee` into a trait.

Before this change, we were able to query `api.consts.transactionPayment.weightToFee[0]` to effectively obtain this constant. This allowed a client to have all the information it needed to precisely calculate fees, which is something we used very extensively in testing.

What tools are available to expose this now? I believe a custom `RPC` endpoint would work, but this seems like a lot of bloat to add such a small piece of information.

Comment: Another idea I had was to create a sort of "miscellaneous" pallet for things that don't really belong anywhere else, but this also seems like a lot of overhead to expose one tiny value.

Comment: Off the top of my head I see two ways to approach this:
 1. Create a dummy pallet that exposes this constant.
 2. Create a custom runtime api.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. By the way, I cross-posted here and suggested the same ones: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12948